# Is it bad practice to check user authentication in layout?

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework

Would it be bad practice to check user authentication in a layout, and output a different element in the layout if a user is logged-in?

I usually see this done in views, but not the layout.

I tried passing the user authentication value to the layout which is doing what I want, but I don't want to if it is bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should ALWAYS be separate from your view/layout, as in setting whether the user is logged in or etc. Detecting and outputting is another story. Most templating engines, like twig or smarty for example, have if statements and logical operators for checking what values are. Including a different element in a layout is no big deal. That's actually part of the view, is it not? Seems like normal practice to me

tldr: carry on. you sound fine.

Comment: Adding onto this answer, you could create a custom view helper to help you get the guts of the code out of your view, and just call something nice like "if(loginStatus() == true){ //etc..}"